# How to copy MSSQLServer Database automated from one server to another

Tags: database, sql-server-2005, ant

I would like to copy one database (almost all tables) to another server. So far we have done this using the standard MSSQL wizard. We would like to include this work into an automated build we have with ant.
I have found one command line tool: http://dbcopytool.codeplex.com/
Any better ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though I've not done this with Ant, I have done all of this with NAnt (and the links below are for Ant).

I would use the [Sql task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sql.html) to issue a [backup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865.aspx) command, then a [Apply/ExecOn](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/apply.html) command to issue the backup copy to the new server (Or the [Copy task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html)) , and then another Sql task to issue the [restore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858.aspx) on the new server.